# Let $f: [a, b]\rightarrow R$ be differentiable at each point of $[a, b ]$ and $f'(a)=f'(b)$, prove that there's a line passing to $a$ tangent to $f$

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing, solution-verification, extreme-value-theorem

Let $f: [a, b]\rightarrow R$ be differentiable at each point of $[a, b ]$, and suppose
that $f'(a) = f'(b)$. Prove that there is at least one point $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that

$$
f'(c) = \dfrac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}
$$

My attempt:

define $h(x) = \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ on $(a,b]$ and $h(a) = f'(a)$. Notice that $h$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Now $$h'(x) = \dfrac{f'(x)}{x-a}-\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2}$$

Note that we define $h'$ on $(a,b]$

Our goal is to show that an extremum point of $h(x)$ lies in $(a,b)$ so we can claim $h'(c)=0$ for some $c\in (a,b)$.

Moving things around we see that $f'(x) = h'(x)(x-a)+h(x)$ on $(a,b]$. We observe that if $h(x)$ is strictly increasing (or strictly decreasing), then $f'(x)$ is also strictly increasing (or strictly decreasing). Hence a contradiction to $f'(a)=f'(b)$ and so there's an extremum $c$ for $h(x)$. Here, we obtain a contradiction because if we were to avoid a contradiction then $f'(a)>d>f'(d+\epsilon)$ (assuming $f'$ is increasing) for any $\epsilon>0$. Applying an intermidate-value-theorem type lemma to $f'$ we contradict monotonicity. Hence, $f(a)<f(a+\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Therefore, $h'(c)=0$ implies $$\dfrac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}=f'(c)$$

I am only looking for proof verifications. If my proof is wrong, please $\textbf{only respond with hints}$.

Comment: WLOG you may assume that $a=0$ and $f(a)=0$.

Comment: It is possible to have a function that has no extremum and yet is not strictly increasing. But you merely need to show $h'(c)=0,$ which does not require an extremum.

Comment: @DavidK You mean a constant function? Maybe I should say monotinic? But it doesn't affect the overall logic to the proof does it?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yes you're right, but I liked the aesthetic of the expression as it is.

Comment: One could say a constant function is its own extremum. I was instead thinking of something that takes on all values but has a constant part, like $f(x)=\begin{cases}-x^2&x\leq0,\\0&0<x<1,\\(x-1)^2&x\geq1.\end{cases}$

Comment: Monotonically increasing doesn't contradict $f'(a)=f'(b).$ I think you need to capture some of the "strict" sense. Maybe consider that if $h'(x)$ is never zero at any point in $(a,b),$ what are the possible signs of $h'(x)$?

Comment: @DavidK could you explan to me on what interval we are considering $f(x)$? (the piece-wise function). We need to fix an interval before defining $h(x)$

Comment: Note: something "like" the given piecewise function. The given function is an example if $a<0$ and $b>1$; otherwise, transform so the constant section is strictly inside $(a,b).$ In fact you then have extrema on $[a,b]$ but they are not where the derivative is zero.

Comment: Perhaps the point of confusion is just the use of the word "extremum" when what you really want is "value of $c$ such that $h'(c)=0$".

Comment: @DavidK The extremum is for $h(x)$. I should have made it clearer. After finding the extremum $(c,h(c))$ of $h(x)$, we note that the derivative at the extremum for $h(c)=0$

Comment: Sigh. I should have written $$h(x)=\begin{cases}-x^2&x\leq0,\\0&0<x<1,\\(x-1)^2&x\geq1.\end{cases}$$ I wasn't thinking of your particular function $f$, just non-strictly increasing functions and functions without extrema in general.

Comment: @DavidK Yes! I see your point now. That was my initial thought about monotonicity. Barring constant functions, if we change strictly to monotonic, the argument should hold. 

In a fundamental way, we are trying to contradict injectivity of $h(x)$ so we can get an extremum. That's another perspective.

Comment: True, the only monotonic $f'$ that satisfies $f'(a)=f'(b)$ is a constant $f'.$ You've probably proved that already at some point.

Comment: @DavidK Yes! Thank. you for your comments. It helped me solidify my understanding

Answer (score 1):

A few small critiques:

> Note that we define ℎ′ on (,]

should instead be "for $a < x \le b$". You're not *defining* $h'$; you're evaluating it (using the quotient rule, etc.) and then noting the domain in which this evaluation is valid.

> Our goal is to show that an extremum point of $ℎ()$ lies in $(,)$ so we can claim $ℎ′()=0$ for some $ \in (,)$.

I'd rewrite this as

> Our goal is to show that for some $c$ strictly between $a$ and $b$, $c$ is an extreme point for $h$. We can then conclude that $h'(c) = 0$.

Given how sensitive the argument is, it might be worth clarifying what you mean by "extreme point." If $f$ is constant, for instance, then $h$ is also constant, and many folks would find it odd to say that a constant function has extreme points (although many others would be fine with it).

....and that's where I stopped reading, because I need to go do other things.